# YouTube Api 3.0

Tags: php, youtube

I have the authentication all working, but when i try to get a list of categories using the php library:

```
// $client is the google client object
$youtube = new Google_YoutubeService($client);
$youtube->videoCategories->listVideoCategories("id");
```

i get the response:

'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories?part=id: (400) No filter selected'

There is no option in listVideoCategories for "filter", the only accepted params are $part and optional params...nothing to do with filters?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need to need to provide either the category id's you want or the region for which you want all categories. You can try it and read the details here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list

This should work:

```
// $client is the google client object
$youtube = new Google_YoutubeService($client);
$categories = $youtube->videoCategories->listVideoCategories('id', array('regionCode' => 'US'));
```